# Need to copy new information to one of two other worksheets based on the selected dropdown menu

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, auto-update

I have 3 worksheets used by 3 different people. Sheet "Builder Contact" needs to feed into either sheet "Res Jobs" if "Res" is selected or into "Comm Jobs" if "Comm" is selected. The information being copied isn't going to same column (ex. "Builder Contact" column 1, 10, 2, 4, 5 would be "Res Jobs" column 1, 2, 3, 7, 8 respectively).

I also need this to be updated automatically when "Res" or "Comm" is selected from the drop down menu in the "Builder Contact" Sheet. My current code can currently do it, but I have to hit run every time and it repeats everything because of the loop. But the loop is how I am currently getting the "x" value I need to find which row to copy all of the information.

```
Sub Res_Comm()
    Sheets("Builder Contact").Select
    ' Find the last row of data
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Loop through each row
    For x = 2 To FinalRow
        ' Decide if to copy based on column K (column with the drop down menu to select "Res" or "Comm")
        ThisValue = Cells(x, 11).Value
        If ThisValue = "Res" Then
            Cells(x, 1).Copy
            Sheets("Res Jobs").Select
            NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("Builder Contact").Select
            
            Cells(x, 10).Copy
            Sheets("Res Jobs").Select
            NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Cells(NextRow, 2).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("Builder Contact").Select
            
            Cells(x, 2).Copy
            Sheets("Res Jobs").Select
            NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Cells(NextRow, 3).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("Builder Contact").Select
            
            Cells(x, 4).Copy
            Sheets("Res Jobs").Select
            NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Cells(NextRow, 7).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("Builder Contact").Select
            
            Cells(x, 5).Copy
            Sheets("Res Jobs").Select
            NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Cells(NextRow, 8).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            ' This column is asking for the source, which in this case would be the name of the user for "Builder Contact"
            Cells(NextRow, 6).Value = "Dan"
            
            
            
        ElseIf ThisValue = "Comm" Then
            Cells(x, 1).Copy
            Sheets("Comm Jobs").Select
            NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Cells(NextRow, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("Builder Contact").Select
            
            Cells(x, 10).Copy
            Sheets("Comm Jobs").Select
            NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Cells(NextRow, 3).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("Builder Contact").Select
            
            Cells(x, 2).Copy
            Sheets("Comm Jobs").Select
            NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Cells(NextRow, 4).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("Builder Contact").Select
            
            Cells(x, 4).Copy
            Sheets("Comm Jobs").Select
            NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Cells(NextRow, 8).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("Builder Contact").Select
            
            Cells(x, 5).Copy
            Sheets("Comm Jobs").Select
            NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Cells(NextRow, 9).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            
            Cells(NextRow, 7).Value = "Dan"
        End If
    Next x
End Sub
```

[Builder Contact][1][Res Jobs][2]

It won't let me add the photos directly yet, but hopefully the links work.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynDvD.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bokm.png

Comment: And if this makes a difference, the other two people will be adding similar information on their sheets and editing to the row that is being copied over, hence why the the columns don't match up and why I don't do a range instead of the individual cells. My current code doesn't interfere with that at the moment.

Comment: It repeats everything because your code has a For Loop starting at Row 2 and it reads from there every time you run it. You have to think of a way of how to do it without that if you dont want it to repeat. To run it automatically you also need to make this a Workbook event. Do you need this after changing the value on a cell, you can. But what if there is a typo? Is there an example of what is being added and what is the result you want?

Comment: Sharing screenshots of your worksheets would do wonders. How did you figure the code would know when a row had already been copied? What is this *"Decide if to copy based on column D"* all about (sounds like crucial to me)? At which moment should the automatic copy take place? What is *"Dan"* all about? Please elaborate on these and nay other issues (ideas). You can [edit your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71682471/edit) at any time.

Comment: I updated the post to include links to the "Builder Contact" Sheet and the "Res Jobs" Sheet. Also, my apologies, "Decide if to copy based on column D" is column K (column 11). The automatic copy should happen when they select "Res" or "Comm" from their drop down menu in column K. That should be the last information that gets entered. I will deal with getting them to do that properly unless you have another suggestion.

Comment: I understand it repeats because of the For Loop, but it was the closest I got to making it work. The loop was a stand in for "x" so that the code had something to reference for the row being copied. The event will be when they select "Res" or "Comm" from the drop down menu. That should prevent typos from occurring, but even if they do try typing it in wrong, the event shouldn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though your users enter either "Res" or "Comm" in column K.  The code below should write the values from the appropriate column of "Builder Contact" sheet to the appropriate columns of either the "Res Jobs" or the "Comm Jobs".  You need to put this code in the module for the "Builder Contact" sheet. To do that double-click "Builder Contact" under "Microsoft Excel Objects" as seen here.

[image]

Then paste in this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim s As Worksheet
    Dim source_columns As Variant
    Dim dest_columns As Variant
    Dim next_row As Long
    Dim x As Long
    
    If Target.Column = 11 Then
        If Target.Value = "Res" Then
            Set s = Sheets("Res Jobs")
            dest_columns = Array(1, 2, 3, 7, 8)
        ElseIf Target.Value = "Comm" Then
            Set s = Sheets("Comm Jobs")
            dest_columns = Array(1, 3, 4, 8, 9)
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        source_columns = Array(1, 10, 2, 4, 5)
        
        next_row = s.Cells(s.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
        For x = 0 To UBound(source_columns)
             s.Cells(next_row, dest_columns(x)).Value = Cells(Target.Row, source_columns(x))
        Next

        s.Cells(next_row, 6).Value = "Dan"
        
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want the user to choose from a dropdown list and then run the code you provided.  If so, you want to put a "form-control comboxbox" on the worksheet.  Here's where you find it on the developer tab of the ribbon.

[image]

Once you place the combobox on the sheet, right-click it and choose "Format Control"

[image]

This will allow you to configure the control.  Under "Input Range", select the range where you have the values you want to appear in the list of possibilities.  Under "cell link" put the cell where you want the value to go.  In that cell, you will get a number that indicates which item is selected.  Change your code to act differntly based on that number instead of res/comm.

Finally, right-click the combobox and choose "assign macro" to choose the macro you want to run when the user makes a choice.

[image]

Comment: Am I going to need to add a button for each row? And right now I have the row value based on a loop. What would you recommend to change it to?

Comment: This is going to require some back and forth, so it would be better done in chat:  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243500/gove-and-dailystoked.  Join me there now if you can

Comment: I also don't have a high enough rep to do that yet. I just started. I will work on that.

Comment: I don't think it takes any rep to join a chat room

Comment: "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here". I can see what you are saying though

Comment: I have to go to a work meeting.  I'll comment here again when I am free

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243525/discussion-between-gove-and-dailystoked).